# Python module to beep Windows motherboard speaker at specified frequency and length?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, audio, motherboard

Windows 8.1, Python 3.4

---

I'm looking for a Python library that will allow me to beep the speaker on my motherboard for a specified length at a specified frequency. I've looked around, and the main suggestion was to use the winsound module. However, this only sends the sound to my *external* speaker and not the internal one. I'm looking to try to make a simple chiptune ("8-bit") song using my motherboard speaker. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work: https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html ?

Looks similar to C# Console.Beep. pass in frequency and duration.

Comment: As I said, that was what I tried. It sends sounds to the external speaker on my system, not the internal one. I haven't found a similar module that works.

Comment: Based on this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx it seems windows will use your default speaker. Try setting it so your Mobo speaker is the default.

Comment: In the past the beep.sys kernel driver would call `HalMakeBeep`. This HAL function does the low-level port I/O to make the 8254 timer play a square-wave beep on the PC speaker. In Windows 7 beep.sys instead directs beep requests back to the user-mode sound system. You'd have to install a custom driver to get the old behavior back.